# Net Core: Override WebApplicationFactory Services DbContext with InMemory Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am customizing WebApplicationFactory to use Startup, appsettings from original Application project.

Purpose is to create Integration test which points to original application startup. The appsettings json is following for dbcontext:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog = TestDB; Integrated Security=True"
```

I want to override Services to use inmemory database, from variable below. How would I conduct this?

**Custom Web Application Factory:**

```
namespace Integrationtest
{
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configurationBuilder) =>
            {
                var type = typeof(TStartup);
                var path = @"C:\OriginalApplication";

                configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile($"{path}\\appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Integration Test:**

```
public class DepartmentAppServiceTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<OriginalApplication.Startup>>

{
    public dbContextTest context;
    public CustomWebApplicationFactory<OriginalApplication.Startup> _factory;
    public DepartmentAppServiceTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<OriginalApplication.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task DepartmentAppTest()
    {
        using (var scope = _factory.Server.Host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            context.Department.Add(new Department { DepartmentId = 2, DepartmentCode = "123", DepartmentName = "ABC" });
            context.SaveChanges();

            var foo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDepartmentAppService>();
            var departmentDto = await foo.GetDepartmentById(2);
            Assert.Equal("123", departmentDto.DepartmentCode);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to override the Services database to use inmemory database, from this variable below. How would I conduct this?

```
           var dbtest = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

           var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDB")
            .Options;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`WebHostBuilder.ConfigureTestServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.webhostbuilderextensions.configuretestservices?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to adjust the service configuration that the integration test server uses. That way, you can reconfigure your database context to use a different configuration. This is also covered in the [integration testing chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.0) of the documentation.

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    // …

    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        // remove the existing context configuration
        var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>));
        if (descriptor != null)
            services.Remove(descriptor);

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDB"));
    });
}
```

The configuration passed to `ConfigureTestServices` will always run *after* the `Startup.ConfigureServices`, so you can use this to override the real services for your integration tests.

For most situations, it will be enough to simply register some other type over the existing registration to make it apply everywhere. Unless you actually retrieve multiple services of a single type (by injecting `IEnumerable<T>` somewhere), this will not have a negative effect.

Comment: I edited answer, might want to remove extra spaces and clean up my formatting, Thanks !

Comment: shouldn't the example use ConfigureTestServices?   You have ConfigureServices.

Comment: @user1821052 That was apparently changed in the edit by OP. I have rechecked with the current guidance and reverted/updated my answer to reflect how it likely should be.

Comment: @poke when I try to do this, I get error that it finds two database services, one in memory and another one to the real one, and it is only allowed to create one. How can I get rid of this ?

Comment: @kuldeep Make sure that the part about removing existing context configuration is done correctly.

Comment: @poke , this is the part I am not able to achieve. WIll this work with 3.1 as well ?  Is there somewhere a sample I can look into ? THank you

Comment: Without explicitly removing the existing registration it did not work for me (in .NET6). Thanks for guidance @poke.